# OpenGL & C++ : glBegin/glEnd

Tags: c++, opengl

```
          glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for(i; i <= degree; i++)
        {
            float 
            sunX=-200/2*cos(i*M_PI/180),
            sunZ=200/2*sin(i*M_PI/180);

            glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            glVertex3f(sunX, 0, sunZ);
        }
        glEnd();
```

This code is work. But...

```
for(i; i <= degree; i++)
        {
            float 
            sunX=-200/2*cos(i*M_PI/180),
            sunZ=200/2*sin(i*M_PI/180);
                            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
            glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            glVertex3f(sunX, 0, sunZ);
                            glEnd();
        }
```

But this doesn't work. Wtf? Where is logic?
I need to insert another code into for cycle for text out:

```
glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);
glListBase(1000);
glCallLists(strlen(text), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text);
glPopAttrib();
```

but i can't to insert it, because beetwen glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP) and glEnd() it does not work. And i can't write glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP), glEnd() inside for cycle, because it does not work there.

Comment: Use [vertex arrays](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html)

Comment: Don't use glBegin/glEnd and the rest of the old pipeline... it is no longer good practice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);` you are starting a brand new triangle strip. It will not be connected to the other vertices from previous iterations of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [glBegin](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml)

> "... Lines, triangles, quadrilaterals, and polygons that are incompletely specified are not drawn. Incomplete specification results when either too few vertices are provided to specify even a single primitive or when an incorrect multiple of vertices is specified. The incomplete primitive is ignored; the rest are drawn. ..."

You need to specify a minimum number of vertices between  a glBegin/glEnd pair; the number is dependant on the parameter you supply to glBegin.

1. `GL_POINTS` : 1
2. `GL_LINES`, `GL_LINE_*`: 2
3. `GL_TRIANGLES`, `GL_TRIANGLE_*` : 3
4. `GL_QUADS`, `GL_QUAD_*` : 4